# Firebase not return anything on angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to fetch data from my firebase account

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.factory("Items", function($firebaseArray) {
  var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://tukang-urut-dayang.firebaseio.com/senarai_pelanggan");
  return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
})
function MyCtrl($scope,Items) {
   $scope.items = Items;

}
```

Unfortunately the return of `Items` does not give any outputs at all. Did I miss something?

I just follow this tutorial

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html#section-list-view

---

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imranhamzah/puap07ar/1/)

Comment: Have you followed the authentication instructions in the tutorial?

Comment: Does it affected the resilt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using some incompatible versions of the libraries.

I updated your jsfiddle to use these includes:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js
https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.0/firebase.js
https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.2.0/angularfire.min.js
```

And updated the controller definition to:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['firebase']);

myApp.factory("Items", function($firebaseArray) {
  var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://tukang-urut-dayang.firebaseio.com/senarai_pelanggan");
  return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
})
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope,Items) {
   $scope.items = Items;
});
```

With these changes it works.

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/puf/puap07ar/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where is the specific documentation for this version?